# Vectorizing which statements in R

Tags: r

I currently have the following code.

```
names <- c("Red","Green","Blue","Orange","Yellow")
aMatrix <- matrix(data=0,nrow=5,ncol=5)
df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=5,ncol=2))
colnames(df)=c("Number","name")    
selectedRows=sample(1:5, 5)
samples=sample(1:5, 5)
for (i in 1:5){
    df[i,"Number"]=i
    df[i,"name"]=names[samples[i]]
}
for (i in 1:5){
    aMatrix[i,which(names==df[selectedRows[i],"name"])]=1
}
```

Is there a way to vectorize the last loop so that it runs faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done by creating a column index with `match`, `cbind` the row index with the column index to extract the values from `aMatrix` and assign those to 1

```
aMatrix2 <- aMatrix # before the assignment in OP's code
aMatrix2[cbind(seq_len(nrow(aMatrix)), match(df$name[selectedRows], names))] <- 1
```

-checking

```
identical(aMatrix, aMatrix2)
#[1] TRUE
```